# I can't connect to SQLite db, but I don't get any error (C#)

Tags: c#, sqlite

When I try to connect the SQLite database the program is waiting, do nothing. Here my code:

```
class DAO
{
    private static readonly String connectionString = @"Data Source=D:\database.db;Version=3;";

    public String GetConfig(String key)
    {
        String value = "";

        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

            command.CommandText = "SELECT `value` FROM config WHERE `key`=@key";

            command.Parameters.Add("key", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = key;

            conn.Open();

            object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result != null)
            {
                value = Convert.ToString(result);
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

The program is waiting on `conn.Open();` line, but doesn't throw any errors... 
Where is the problem?

Comment: Move your database out of the root of disk D:. Usually these places are read-only

Comment: I tried, unfortunately nothing has changed.

Comment: The command will execute after the connection is opened. But if I move up the opening, is still wrong.

Comment: Just check your connection string.this link may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631602/how-to-set-sql-server-connection-string

Comment: Problem solved... I forgot to set the Copy to output dir property of sqlite3.dll file.

Comment: please describe what you did, i have the same problem