# Issues connecting to a SQL Server database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I found this article for the majority of the code here [How to set SQL Server connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631602/how-to-set-sql-server-connection-string).

Here's what I have though:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\Instance;" +
                        "Initial Catalog=Database;" +
                        "User id=root;Password=pass;";

try
{
     conn.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Database.dbo.Table" +
                                      "VALUES ('stg', 'stg1', 'stg2', 'stg3');", conn);

try
{
     conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

A lot of the previous code was giving me errors. At one point, I was getting an error that I couldn't connect to the instance. This was an issue with the '\'. It was recognizing it as an escape character, so I did double '\' to get rid of that, so I'm not getting that error anymore, so that shouldn't be the problem.

I was getting an error about the wrong username and password. I'm using SQL Server Authentication and the code I was previously using was specifying Windows authentication. I'm not getting that error anymore.

As of right now, the code executes all the way through with no errors. When I check on the database though (I'm using SQL Server Management Studio), nothing gets inserted into the table. I have ran the Insert statement directly and it works fine, so I'm not sure what the issue is here. Also, I'm using VS 2013.

Comment: Don't want to be too harsh, but did you read any tutorial on ADO.NET before starting this kind of programming? You have a very powerful tool in your hands and you should try to understand a little of how it works otherwise these kind of problems will be a recurring scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not executing the query. Add this after creating the command object:

```
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Side note: You should rather have a `try...catch` around all the code, and use `using` blocks for the connection and command. That will ensure that the objects are closed and disposed properly whatever happens:

```
try {

  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()) {

    conn.ConnectionString =
      "Data Source=(localdb)\\Instance;" +
      "Initial Catalog=Database;" +
      "User id=root;" +
      "Password=pass;";

    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Database.dbo.Table" +
                                      "VALUES ('stg', 'stg1', 'stg2', 'stg3');", conn)) {
      myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

  }

} catch (Exception ex) {
  Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Writing `catch (Exception)` is a bad habit you shouldn't start new programmers on. At the very least, catch the specific exception you're expecting (in this case, `SqlException`). Better yet, if your program has no strategy for handling the exception, don't and let it crash.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: That is a good point, and I was thinking of mentioning that, but kept it closer to the original code. Writing the error message to the console seems to be a temporary measure for handling the error anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.90).aspx) to use the insert-command at all. Therefore nothing is inserted.

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Database.dbo.Table" +
                                      "VALUES ('stg', 'stg1', 'stg2', 'stg3');", conn);
int inserted = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You should also use the `using`-statement to ensure that all unmanaged resources are disposed and the connection gets closed even on error. Then you don't need to use `conn.Close` explicitly.