# Whats wrong with my connection string?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hello please help me out with this connection string  and even my procedure properties are attached

```
try
{
   conn = new SqlConnection("Server=RM-MOBL\MSSQLSERVER1;DataBase=master;Trusted_Connection=True;");

   conn.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.new", conn);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   Console.WriteLine(" connection success");
}
// I hope I have mentioned correct connection string but 
// not able to execute my stored procedure
```

i am facing error

![please see error here ][3]

Comment: What kind of error you are getting?

Comment: Check this (first ansver) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631602/how-to-set-sql-server-connection-string

Comment: Check out this page for connection strings to any kind of database: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/. Also, you did not tell us what is the error you are getting - this would really help us to answer your question.

Comment: Check out guys i have updated error message has well

Comment: Either precede connection string with `@` or use \\ to avoid escape character \ effects.

Comment: Arvo yes your correct its working fine!  thank mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code might not be a best way to Connect the database.

In your web.config add these lines which will connect to your database inside `<configuration>` section

```
<connectionStrings >
    <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Server=ServerName;Database=DatabaseName;User ID=UserId;Password=Password;Trusted_Connection=False;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

And in your C# file add these references

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

Inside Public Class add this Connection

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Now you can open the Connection by having `con.Open();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,if you are using local machine

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=RANJITHM-OBL\MSSQLSERVER1;initial catalog=master;integrated security=true");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.new", conn);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
   rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   Console.WriteLine(" connection success");
```