# SQL database connection error

Tags: c#, connection-string, sqlconnection, local-database, sdf

I am encountering an error while running C# application that containing SQL Server Database, the problem is that the moment i press start button my database connection failed, and a red cross appears near the database icon "as illustrated in the posted image", and this cross disappeared when i rebuild the solution.
[image]
 can any one help me

```
 SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Server=local;Database=Books;integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter Da;
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
        Da = new SqlDataAdapter(" Select * From Sadera", Con);
        Da.Fill(Dt);
        saderaDataGridView.DataSource = Dt;
```

Comment: Can you edit the post with the connection string you're using ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631602/how-to-set-sql-server-connection-string

Comment: I think you should check your connectionstring.

Comment: You haven't told us what database you're using, but my guess would be to change your connection string to `Data Source=|DataDirectory|Books.sdf;integrated Security=True` and ensure the Copy To Output Directory property of Books.sdf is "copy if newer".