# SQL Server : Error 40 cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, google-maps

I am working on a project where I'm using SQL for local database, .NET for UI design and C# for coding. I'm supposed to map the locations mentioned in the database on google map. But as I run the application, server connection is getting closed automatically an error 40 is being raised. I have set firewall to allow the SQL server, set TCP/IP port to 1433, restarted the services still facing the same error.

Besides I'm not familiar with .net and C#. I am not able to code the SAVE button in database form. And as I have records more than 2000, it is not possible for me to insert the data manually. I have found 1 code regarding this. Can anyone tell me what to do changes in that?

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Integrated security=true;Initial Catalog=Final_Table;Data source=.");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        con.Open();
        string s = "insert into Final_Table values(@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",txtLoc.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtAsset.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtLongi.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", txtLati.Text);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully!");
    }
```

How to link this database to google map using form2. I have MAP button in that form, how can I do that?

Comment: Your connection string is wrong. Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631602/how-to-set-sql-server-connection-string

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: Is SQLEXPRESS service up and running?

Comment: yes it is running

Comment: You have a lot of questions.Please edit your code and post your new connection string. Also post the actual exception text. "Error 40" is of no help

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  that error has been resolved.
my new connection string is: 
con.ConnectionString = @"Server=.\SQLExpress; AttachDbFilename=path_to_the_file; Database=name.mdf; Trusted_Connection= Yes";

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the full error text as well as the changed code