# How to receive data from SQLServer

Tags: c#, web, server

i have a powerfull server , now i installed Microsoft SQLServer on My Server , however , **i want to receive data from my SQLServer** like online program, 
What is next my step? Would i change the **ConnectingString** and this will be ok? 
or it need more something ?
if it is, tell me **Youtube links** or some answers with description .
someone tell me the best way is making "**API**" ,  would someone  tell me whats the best start step ? 
You Know ? this program is working on local database , i want to make that online and i need some description to start. 
if there is any way with API and ConnectingString or something , just tell the key word with some description , or links , videos...

my program developed by C#  .

i can also use MYsql . but my best choice is MSserver for now.

thaks for help .

Comment: Too broad, asking for offsite resources, numerous questions in one post.  Trifecta!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you googling **"Basic C# asp.net tutorial"** and **"publishing asp.net website"** there are tons of tutorials online. There are several minor important considerations and knowledge that you could get by studying those google results.

Basically you don't even need an API, if your program is very small, working locally and you want to make it online, just get a hosting server that allows the .Net Framework that you are using, upload your files. Then change the conectionstring to point to the Public IP/credentials of your sql server (you may have to work with firewall or routes in your server to allow external access)

...I'm not sure if your local software is in windows application/console. If this is the case you would need to rewrite the UI to ASP.NET (so it can be acessed like a page). If you don't want the asp.net behavior, you can use your windows app connecting direcly to your server.

There are several ways of doing this, but i really sugest some basic courses/online training in C# and ASP.NET (Udemy, Pluralsight, etc...)

Your question is too broad, and with imprecise scope. Well, anyway, below is a link to an asp.net tutorial (you will find TONs googling 'C# course/tutorial')
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/

Good luck

Comment: Fine thanks for everything. i have a little qustion, i was think ASP.Net is just for site. my program developed by C# WPF . this may help me ?

Comment: As i said, your question is too broad without further specifications. You saing that your app is WPF, basically just changing the connectionstring would do the work. Instead of using localhost, use your server's IP and credentials, configure your server firewall to allow external connections and everything should be fine (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631602/how-to-set-sql-server-connection-string) - for example:
"Data Source=64.65.234.23;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User id=DatabaseUser;Password=databaseUserpassword";