# How to find correct SQL login details

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms

I'm very new to coding, and recently got a task to connect my `SSMS`/`SWL` Database to Visual Studio 2019.

When I press the button, the DB should connect and a message should pop up saying it's been connected.

I assume I have the incorrect login details, but I'm not sure, and even if I was sure, I wouldn't know how to find the correct login details.

So here's my current button click code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        connectionString = @"Data Source=TRISTAN\SQLEXPRESS ;Initial Catalog=TutorialDB ;User ID=TRISTAN\Tristan; Password=";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        cnn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Open");
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

So, the login detail's I'm using are those shown when launching `SSMS` and the "Connect to Server" box pops up.

Am i using the login details from the correct place "Connect to server window" Or are the details I need somewhere else.

The error message I get when clicking the 'Connect' button `"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'TRISTAN\Tristan'.'"`

I'd appreciate any assistance, please also keep in mind I don't know much Programming language yet, so please keep it simple.

Comment: I read all this twice but could not find an actual question. What is it specifically you are asking? Is it how to show a message? How to catch an exception? How to check a connection string? How to pass user data to a connection string? Something else entirely? Please also refer to [ask]

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot that part.
Am i using the login details from the correct place "Connect to server window" Or are the details i need somewhere else. 

I also forgot the error message i get "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'TRISTAN\Tristan'.'"

Comment: Did you add the password to that connectionstring?

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/help-topics/data-link-pages?view=sql-server-ver15. Create a .txt file, rename to .udl. Open it and try to get a valid connection. Then open that file using notepad and copy/paste the connection string.

Comment: There is no password when i launch SSMS so i didn't insert any password.

Comment: Well, connecting from code requires the password

Comment: Likely you are connecting using integrated security (windows credentials). Again, use the UDL file to build your connection string and copy/paste it.

Comment: Wait, in SSMS is the user field disabled? If yes then you are using a trusted connection and you don't need to specify the username but you need to add  to the connectionstring _Trusted_Connection=Yes_

Comment: Duplicate of [How to set SQL Server connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15631602/1260204)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should catch error while opening a connection and display it to the user, something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string connectionString = @"Data Source=TRISTAN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TutorialDB;Trusted_Connection=True;";
  using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    try
    {
      cnn.Open();
      MessageBox.Show("Connection Open");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to database: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
      cnn.Close();
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what that means/does or where to insert it ?

Comment: And I changed connection string to use windows authentication

Comment: I'm getting 2 errors with that code

Catch (SqlException e): "A local parameter named e cannot be declared in that scope (error is on the 'e')

MessageBox.Show(("Error while connecting to database: " + e.Message); 
 CS1026: ) Expected (Error on the semi colon)

Comment: fixed, I overlooked that e is  a parameter in winforms event

Comment: It worked!
Thank you so much.

How do i go about understanding what you've done now.

Comment: read about try/catch block https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions or watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYmRJDBnKWw

Answer (score 1):

- Open Visual Studio
- Go to View tab -> Server Explorer
- Right click to "Data Connections" tab
- Add connection
- Select the server name
- Select the database
- Ok
- Server Explorer -> Data Connections -> myServer\myDB.dbo -> right click and then Properties
- Copy the connection string from Properties View

Write this code;

```
            string connectionString;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            connectionString = @"***YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING***";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
            if (cnn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Open");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            if (cnn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Closed");
            }
```

Comment: It opens connection and checks your connection state (open or not)
If your connection is open. Message box will show "Connection open" messages
And connection is closed.
And it checks your connection for closed state

Also i explained how can you find the correct connection string (with connection details)