# How to set value of connection string in app.config using an argument from Main function in console app

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application, connection-string, app-config

I have a c# console app that uses entity framework. In the app config file I define the connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;Data source={argument from Main function}" providerName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My context.cs

```
public class SinergyContext : DbContext
{
    public SinergyContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection") { }

    public DbSet<RejectedData> RejectedErrors { get; set; }
}
```

My Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // arg[0] contains the connection string data source
```

Is it possible to set the connection string in Program.cs file ?

Comment: You can follow this other SO example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15631602/1188197.  Read in your connection string and create the db connection from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to pass values to app.config using c# (in main.cs file).
Here is how :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Configuration config = ConfigurationManager
    .OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

  ConnectionStringsSection section = 
    (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");

  section.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString += args[0];

  config.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your DBContext to accept a custom connection string:

```
public class SinergyContext : DbContext
{
    public SinergyContext(string cs) : base(cs) { }

    public DbSet<RejectedData> RejectedErrors { get; set; }
}
```

Then instantiate it via:

```
var db = new SinergyContext("my connection string");
```

If you have to use a provider, you can use a `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`:

```
var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Provider = "JetEntityFrameworkProvider",
    ProviderConnectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;Data source={args[0]}"
};
var db = new SinergyContext(builder.ToString());
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a provider (eg. JetEntityFrameworkProvider) in the instantiation of SinergyContext ? Because without this provider the connection to Access database doesn't work. That is why the app.config was useful because it contains the provider

Comment: Is this EF Core? Or EF 6?

Comment: Thank you @mxmissile for your help. I did find a way to solve my problem. I published the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can used `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` to get ConnectionString of app config

Example:

```
system.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

or create the context and get its properties

```
context = new SinergyContext();
```